# WCF web service with CROSS Domian Ajax not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, wcf, cross-domain

I am getting error when calling WCF Ajax Request using jsonp
below is my **web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="HttpEndPoint" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" ></endpoint>

        <endpoint
            address="Service1.svc"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And my My Interface

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;

    namespace RestService
    {
        // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IRestServiceImpl" in both code and config file together.
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IRestServiceImpl
        {


            [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                UriTemplate = "getallemp")]
            [return: MessageParameter(Name = "success")]
            string GetAllEmployee();




        }
    }
```

and below is My Service Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using WebService.DataLayer;

namespace RestService
{

    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "RestServiceImpl" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select RestServiceImpl.svc or RestServiceImpl.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {

        public string GetAllEmployee()
        {
            cls_datalayer obj = new cls_datalayer();
            DataTable dt = obj.getDataTableFromQuery("select usercode from users where empstatus='A'");

            return ConvertDataTabletoString(dt);
        }

        public string ConvertDataTabletoString(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = 50000000;
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }




    }
}
```

When i call this from browser its give [From Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSWB7.png)

but when i try this from Ajax request using cross domain then i am getting error

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost:59672/RestServiceImpl.svc/getallemp',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert();

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    //console.log(xhr);
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");

                }
            });
```

then i get error please check attachments [Attachment 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR4kg.png)

[Attachment 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk0nQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is worked better for me than the Web.config version:

Create a `Global.asax`

Add this code to the `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```